# unable to install or run C# application on client PC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, debuggervisualizer

I have developed a desktop application in c# & SQL server 2012 using Visual Studio 2013. I have included the reference for **Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers** and set **copy local : true**. 
The application runs perfectly on client systems with windows 8, 10. 
But its showing this error while installing on a windows 7 system.
- OS Windows 7 Ultimate
- already installed .NET Framework 4.5
- installed Report Viewer.exe 2012 
- installed report viewer.msi 2010
- installed sqlclr types 
- the system doesnt have any microsoft c++ redistributable , i am not sure whether it has any impact.
I checked in the assembly folder, but couldnt find the  **Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll**
Am I missing any prerequisites here? How to solve this issue so that i can install the application

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt1Ko.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It needs the Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll in the global assembly cache. The GAC is the area where libs are placed which can be accessed from all of the system.
It's kinda a ugly fix but you could place this lib in the same or subdirectory of the same directory where the application is.

Is it possibly that you haven't installed VS on that Win7 machine but on the others?

Answer (score 0):

Unintentionally the Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll had been included in the project reference. And in the client system the specified dll could not be found even after trying to install it. Hence I removed it from reference and then it worked perfectly fine without any issues. I guess instead of report visualizer i have included debuggervisualizer. It was a manual error. 
Thank you for your support